# How to NDSolve a set of equations, one of which itself contains NIntegrate of a desired function?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

How to NDSolve a set of equations, one of which itself contains NIntegrate of a desired function waited to be solved by NDSolve first? For example,

```
f[x_]:=NIntegrate[g[x0],{x0,0,x}];
NDSolve[{f'[x]==g[x],g'[x]==f[x],f[0]==0,g[0]==0},{f,g},{x,0,1}];
```

You can construct many specific examples like this one, mayebe my question are too general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not

```
{sol} = NDSolve[{f'[x] == g[x], g'[x] == f[x], f[0] == 1, g[0] == 0}, {f, g}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

omitting the definition of `f`?

Check:

```
{Inactivate@NIntegrate[g[x0], {x0, 0, x}], f[x]} /. sol /. x -> 0.5 // Activate
(*  {0.521095, 0.521095}  *)
```